# Recursive method to count the number of combinations

Tags: java, recursion

this is a java code that recursively counts the number of payments in specific coins (ex. 1, 2, 5, 20, 50 etc.). I have tried to figure out how it works but can't seem to get it. Could somebody please be so kind and explain the math and logic behind the code and how this recursion works? I would really appreciate it.

```
    // Returns the count of ways we can sum  S[0...m-1] coins to get sum n
int count( int S[], int m, int n ){

    // If n is 0 then there is 1 solution (do not include any coin)
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    // If n is less than 0 then no solution exists
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;

    // If there are no coins and n is greater than 0, then no solution exist
    if (m <=0 && n >= 1)
        return 0;

    // count is sum of solutions (i) including S[m-1] (ii) excluding S[m-1]
    return count( S, m - 1, n ) + count( S, m, n-S[m-1] );
}
```

Comment: How is it called? What is S?

Comment: @Behe Looks like an array of the coins to sum

Comment: @Java Devil exactly, it looks like an array of integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method works like this:

1. First statements are the stopping conditions for the current recursion (without these for all cases then you end up with an infinite loop which ultimately end in a StackOverFlow)
2. The final line is where the calculation occurs. Each of the statements is reducing the problem into smaller chunks by:

   - `count( S, m - 1, n )` reduces the number of coins (`m-1`) which excludes the last coin in the next recursive call to
   - `count( S, m, n-S[m-1])` uses the last coin in the array and reduces the sum that is need to reach by the value of that coin

Consider this small example:

```
S[] = {1,2)    // We have a 1 and 2 cent coin
m   = S.length // Consider all possibilities  ( = 2)
n   = 3        // How many ways can we make 3c
               // Obviously with: 1x1c + 1x2c
               //            and: 3x1c
```

The recursion as a tree; left branch = `count( S, m - 1, n )`, right branch = `count( S, m, n-S[m-1])`:

```
                                  m=2;n=3
                                 /        \
                          m=1;n=3          m=2;n=1
                         /       \       /     \
                  m=0;n=3    m=1;n=2   m=1;n=1  m=2;n=-1
                            /     \     /     \
                     m=0;n=2  m=1;n=1 m=0;n=1  m=1;n=0
                             /     \
                       m=0;n=1   m=1;n=0
```

This recursion can be thought of as a [Pre-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) Traversal of this tree.

If you then consider the conditions of the method for where a solution is found or not. So at the leaf nodes where n = 0.

Each which comes about like this:

First solution

1. m=1;n=3 - Exclude the last coin (2c)
2. m=1;n=2 - Use this coin (1c) and reduce by 1
3. m=1;n=1 - Use this coin (1c) and reduce by 1
4. m=1;n=0 - Use this coin (1c) and reduce by 1
5. n = 0 - a solution (3x1c)

Second Solution

1. m=2;n=1 - Use this coin(2c) and reduce by 2
2. m=1;n=1 - Exclude the last coin (2c)
3. m=1;n=0 - Use this coin (1c) and reduce by 1
4. n = 0 - a solution (1x2c + 1x2c)

At each node a value is returned - 0 (no solution) or 1 (a solution) - to add to the total count of solutions found. Once the recursion ends this final value is returned and is the number of solutions.

---

Some additional notes:

- This piece of code will only consider the first `m` coins in the array `S` so to consider all the possible ways the initial call to the method needs to have `m == S.length`
- Assumes that each coin can be used multiple times

---

Code modification with print statements to see the recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] coins = new int[]{1,2};
    System.out.println("Final Count = " + count(coins, coins.length, 3, ""));
}

public static int calls = 0;

public static int count( int S[], int m, int n , String from){
    calls++;
    System.out.print("Call#" + calls + ": " + from + "; m = " + m + "; n = " + n);

    // If n is 0 then there is 1 solution (do not include any coin)
    if (n == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(" - Solution Found");
        return 1;
    }

    // If n is less than 0 then no solution exists
    if (n < 0)
    {
        System.out.println(" - No Solution Found n < 0");
        return 0;
    }

    // If there are no coins and n is greater than 0, then no solution exist
    if (m <=0 && n >= 1)
    {
        System.out.println(" - No Solution Found (other Case)");
        return 0;
    }

    System.out.println();
    // count is sum of solutions (i) including S[m-1] (ii) excluding S[m-1]
    return count( S, m - 1, n , from + "E" ) + count( S, m, n-S[m-1], from + "I" );
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you very very very much for the thorough explanation. This is really what i needed. Sorry for the late reply, it took me some time to get it but now it's cristal clear :)

Comment: sorry to bug you again... but I have one more question. I wanted to print only the valid combinations on the console (for the above example it would be like `1+1+1` and `1+2` if the array would containt only `{1, 2}` and `n=3`) but when I add in the first `if(n==0)` statement the code `System.out.println("(n)"+n+" + "+m+"(m)");` eclipse marks the next if statement (that is `if (n < 0)`) as an compilation error `unreachable code`... could you please tell why this doesn't work?... and also tried other different ways but by posting them would make the message too long to sumbit :( thank you

Comment: @user3185735 I can only assume that after your `if(...)` you are missing the opening `{` and closing `}` braces. Make sure it is in the format `if(condition){statements}`. If you haven't done that then only the first statement after the `if` is conditional and the subsequent lines will always be executed... being a return statement so the rest of the code will not be reachable. If this is not the case, write a new question and leave me a link to it.

Comment: you are right, the `brackets` were missing...  I knew I was a noob but not this noob... sadly still doesn't prints the combinations the way I want them to be printed so back to square 1... i also tried this: `System.out.println(count( S, m - 1, n )+" + "+ count( S, m, n-S[m-1] )+" = "+count( S, m - 1, n ) + count( S, m, n-S[m-1] ));` before the recursive `return` call but all it prints is 0 + 1 = 01 and leads to an StackOverFlow... this is something I don't get... I though it should print the sum of combinations including `S[m-1]` and excluding `S[m-1]`... recursion is thougt...

Comment: @user3185735 StackOverFlow mostly likely means that you are getting an infinite loop. That is to much recursion. Printing strings in recursion can be difficult. I think you are best of writing a new question with what you want and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

From the code, I'm assuming `S` is an array with at least `m` elements, with each element representing an available coin denomination, and `n` is the intended sum.

The comments really say it all, except that the last comment is backwards. `count( S, m - 1, n )` is the number of solutions excluding the last coin in the current range. `count( S, m, n-S[m-1] )` is the number of solutions using that coin.

The exclude case simply drops the last coin in the current range by reducing `m` by one.

The include case uses it by reducing `n` by that coin's value. Since the include case does not also reduce `m`, presumably any coin denomination can be used multiple times. It does not matter if the coin is too big - that is taken care of by returning 0 if `n < 0`.

If anything about the base cases is not clear from the comments, please ask a specific question.